# Remote powershell and prompts that do not wait for user input

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I have script that calls `schtasks.exe` to import exported xml task. Schtasks.exe prompts for user password when script is executed directly on the server.

When I user remote powershell calling the same script gives me this:

```
[remote_server]: .\install.ps1
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "monitor.ps1" has been terminated successfully.
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "monitor.ps1" was successfully deleted.
Please enter the run as password for MYDOMAIN\myuser:
schtasks.exe : ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The problem is the line `Please enter the run as password for MYDOMAIN\myuser:` where normally I can enter the password for logged in user but with remote power shell sessions this never happens.

Comment: please show your schtasks command . Did you use /RU /RP ? if you're running win2k8 you can use the Schedule.service COM have a look : https://gist.github.com/kayasax/6634393

Comment: Command is irrelevant since I can solve the problem by introducing password in the script as command line argument. Your COM code would also need password. The only alternative is to use new task scheduling module which doesn't work in older windoze versions, or to use some password hiding mumbo jumbo via secure string (since the install would be executed by deploying software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a know issue:

[Interactive console applications do not work properly through remoting sessions](http://connectbeta.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/798058/interactive-console-applications-do-not-work-properly-through-remoting-sessions)

Comment: I would guess that this has to do with the console input API functions not working remotely (getting this to work probably isn't trivial). You will need to use a different technique to schedule the task that doesn't prompt for console input on the remote system.

Comment: LOL @mjolinor ... I'll remember that when I need a good reason for suicide.